# How can I make default selectd value in input text box?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

I use typeahead feature in my project:

```
<input type="text" 
ng-model="customPopupSelected" 
placeholder="Custom popup template" 
uib-typeahead="state.id as state.desc for state in states | filter:{name:$viewValue}" 
class="form-control">
```

Here is [Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/nicktest222/JXtaZ/24/).
How can I make by default selected sample_data with id=4?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand the question and the code doesn't match the Plunker. Are you trying to initialize the model value to the object from the "sample_data" array matching id: "4"?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the model with :

```
angular.forEach($scope.sample_data, function(item, index) {
    if (item.id == 4) {
        $scope.monkey = $scope.sample_data[index]
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfwzkh98/)